# GTD with calendar/reminders, sorting

Tags: gtd

Several GTD questions have been asked on SU but I have yet to find a GTD tool that meets my needs.

I need a GTD tool that, in addition to doing GTD, does the following:

- Allows me to schedule meetings.
- Allows sorting of tasks within a context

I have used MonkeyGTD which does a great job of implementing GTD but it fails on the above.

The system must also be web accessible.

Note that to do list tools do not come close to meeting my needs (at least no to do list tool I have seen comes close).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to get things done _and_ schedule meetings?

Comment: Yes, Manni.  Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: To get something done a committee should consist of no more than three people, two of whom are absent.  ~Robert Copeland

Comment: I suggest that you stop worrying about finding the perfect tools and get some things done. So-called productivity porn is a kind of procrastination.

Also, schedule meetings with any tool that the group you're working with uses. That's easiest, as the people already know what to expect.

PS. I use OmniFocus. I wouldn't be surprised if Chandler met your needs.

Comment: For MonkeyGTD, you should be able to resort the tasks in a Context by editing the tiddler.  The format seems pretty simple.

Comment: @ tkadlubo Great advice, but I don't think that is my problem.  My problem is that I'm dropping things because I don't have a good tool to organize what I need to get done.

Comment: Interested in GTD? Join [Personal Productivity and Organization](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity-and-organization-gtd-covey-etc), we are looking for users & experts... :)

Answer (score 6):

Remember the milk, and Google calendar with RTM plug in. [RTM](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/)

[Here](http://blog.rememberthemilk.com/2008/05/guest-post-advanced-gtd-with-remember-the-milk/) is a good article on using RTM to GTD

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any web based solutions. I'm sure there are, but I haven't used any. You didn't mention a platform so this is for the Mac and iPhone and unfortunately, there's no web version either (sorry). If I may though, I *highly* recommend [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/). They both sync up (mac + iPhone) which is really nice. But to meet one of your requirements: it really contextualizes tasks and allows grouping/sorting options on both Mac/iPhone so maybe this is something to (at the very least) checkout.

GTD is a bit generic so, I'm unsure if any (or the majority) of GTD apps specifically include meetings. Someone may know of an app of course, but I thought GTD was a very generic, template-able approach and meetings seem to be a bit specific.

But to address one point:

> Note that to do list tools do not come
>   close to meeting my needs (at least no
>   to do list tool I have seen comes
>   close).

I agree that most tools don't come close to *most* needs. Up until my trial with Things, I really felt that most to-do lists were lame, and at best pretty 'meh'. Things has really helped me organize and manage my time fairly effectively and if they had a web version with meetings, I think it would be perfect from what you described. I've been using it since January and at times, I wonder how in the hell did I lived without it. But I realize my recommendation doesn't meet all your requirements, and I thought it may be beneficial to at the very least look at a supposed 'to-do' list in another light.